# Salesforce REST API - identify source of duplicate error

Tags: salesforce

I use `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Lead` REST API endpoint to create a Lead. I receive the following response:

```
[
    {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "errorCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "fields": []
    }
]
```

I understand that Duplication rules cause such behavior, but it is not possible to receive them via API and somehow understand what is the root of this issue.
So my question: How to understand from such response what fields caused "DUPLICATES_DETECTED"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message this is the result of Duplicate Rules detecting a conflict between the Lead you're attempting to create and an existing record.

You can check the exact details either via the [Apex Debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm) for the transaction or the [Duplicate Error Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_duplicate_error_log.htm&type=0). Another alternative is to [upsert the lead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm). You might still run into duplicate rules but if the record matches and the update (rather than insert) happens, the likelihood of duplication is lower.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make upsert for multiple objects? Via [SObject Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) for example?

Comment: Is it possible to create the External Id field via REST API or only from Salesforce UI?

Comment: It's not possible to upsert a collection via `/composite`, that only does an update. You can write an Apex class that does something like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56458/upserting-objects-in-apex-can-i-assert-which-have-been-inserted-updated/56466#56466) and then expose it as your own (custom) REST API. You can add an external ID field to an object via [CustomField Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm)

Comment: The Composite API CAN do an Upsert. It is done via a PATCH statement. See my notes here https://tddprojects.atlassian.net/wiki/x/AQDpGg

Comment: @JodieM Yes but it's worth noting that it won't work for a generic collection of sObjects. You can upsert individual records and Composite will let you do that with a limit of 5-25 records per call, depending on how you structure the call. This [SFSE Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274694/can-you-upsert-using-composite-sobject-tree) is a good example of a Composite with an upsert.

Comment: Sure but the OP was asking about Lead.

Comment: Our comment was in response to OP's comment: _Is it possible to make upsert for multiple objects? Via SObject Collections_